# "Ich bin + Beruf" vs. "Ich arbeite als + Beruf"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Sprachunterricht. Thema: Berufe.

Folgende Frage hätte ich: Sind diese Aussagen bedeutungsgleich?

> (1) Ich bin Dolmetscher.
>
> (2) Ich arbeite als Dolmetscher.

Wäre es möglich, den Satz (2) auch wie folgt zu interpretieren? – *eigentlich  habe ich Ingenieurwesen studiert, konnte aber leider keinen Job finden, deshalb arbeite ich nun als Dolmetscher/Taxifahrer/Kellner* usw.

Danke schön!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the semantics in these sentences are not specific for the German language. They would indeed apply for any language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kurz: (1) möglicherweise, (2) "ja".

Man kann u.U. auch sagen: "Ich bin Maurer" und z.B. überhaupt nichts arbeiten. Um solche Fälle von vorneherein klarzustellen, würde man normalerweise sowas sagen wie:

> Von Beruf bin ich eigentlich Maurer, arbeite aber derzeit als Gärtner.

Comment: Würde ich so nicht unterschreiben. Man kann ihn so interpretieren, aber dass macht kaum jemand. Ich hab es jedenfalls noch nie gehört.

Comment: @OddDev es steht ja in der Antwort schon "u.U."!

Comment: @Beta Da hast du mich glaub falsch verstanden. Ich habe eher bemängelt, dass (2) pauschal mit "ja" beantwortet wird. Das halte ich für eher gewagt :) Also wenn ich es richtig verstanden hab, wird der zweite Satz, also "Ich arbeite als Dolmetscher", so beantwortet, als ob die Interpretation in der Frage zutrifft. Ich glaube aber kaum, dass diesen Satz in der Realität irgendjemand so interpretieren würde, zumal man z.B. in Deutschland für fast jeden Beruf qualifiziert sein muss. Man ist nicht einfach so Maurer oder Dolmetscher, weil man das jetzt halt gerade behauptet. Weißt du was ich mein?

Comment: @tofro oder OddDev: bevor meine Frage geschlossen wird, könntet Ihr mir bitte bei der folgenden Sache helfen: wenn ich es richtig verstanden habe, ist die Version „Ich bin Ingenieur“ zu bevorzugen, wenn z.B. jemand das beruflich macht, was man erlernt hat, stimmt's? Aber der folgende Satz „ich arbeite als Reinigungskraft“ klingt netter/korrekter (leider fällt mir gerade das richtige Adjektiv nicht ein) als „ich bin Reinigungskraft“, nicht wahr? Bitte korrigiert mich, wenn ich falsch liege... Vielen Dank!

Comment: "Ich bin Reinigungskraft" ist aus meiner Sicht genauso korrekt wie "Ich arbeite als Reinigungskraft". "Ich bin..." drückt hier nach meinem Empfinden eine etwas größere Identifikation mit der Tätigkeit aus, ansonsten ist der Unterschied gering. Etwas anders liegt der Fall beim Ingenieur. "Ich bin Ingenieur" hat eine größere Bandbreite der Bedeutungen. Es kann dasselbe bedeuten wie "Ich arbeite als Ingenieur". Es kann aber auch sein, dass die betreffende Persion ein Ingenieursstudium absolviert hat und jetzt einer anderen Tätigkeit nachgeht.

Comment: @Rha Der Ingineur könnte hypothetisch auch sagen "Ich arbeite als Reinigungskraft"... Natürlich ist beides "korrekt" - Nur unterschiedlich interpretierbar.

Comment: @OddDev Weder Dolmetscher noch Maurer sind in Deutschland geschützte Berufsbezeichnungen. Beides kann man also "halt gerade" behaupten.